# What kind of header signature is 0x7473657571655220?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to read an excel file with apache POI. However, at runtime i get a NotOLE2FileException. [I've found this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33879515/notole2fileexception-invalid-header-signature-read-0x0000000000000000-expecte), which is similar, but here the error is clearly that there is no file at all. I actually have a file, and have a signature, but I have no clue what kind of signature that is, or how I can read the file. Google yields no results.

My Code:

```
File file = new File("mypath/myfile.xls");
if(!file.exists()){
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("File does not exist");
}   
try {
    Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(file); //<--- throws exception

//etc...
```

Error:

```
org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NotOLE2FileException: Invalid header signature; read 0x7473657571655220, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:181)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:140)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:232)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:168)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:250)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:222)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:201)
    at providers.ExcelFileReader.getRequestsFromExcelFile(ExcelFileReader.java:25)
    at Test.main(Test.java:13)
```

I just need to understand why my xls-file has a strange header, and what that means, to be able to solve this one. Does anyone know? Might there be any work arounds?

**Update:** as far as I can see, it is a perfectly valid excel file:
[image]

Comment: Wow. The file is indeed a list of requests from a system I am extracting data from. I just did that yes. I don't have too much experience with how excel-file formats should look in notepad, but the relevant file displays as a tab separated pure text file, where every row is a new line.

Comment: Seems right. You've pretty much already answered my question here. Would you just write those in a short answer? Deciphering the signature was very cool :). And Now I just have to figure out how to read a tab spaced file instead. Problem solved so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ASCII equivalent of `0x74736575716552` is `"tseuqeR"` (`"Request"` spelled backwards). It appears that you have a plain text file that you are asking POI to open as an Excel file.

I checked [Wikipedia's List of file signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) first and when I didn't find anything used an ASCII table (`man ascii` if you are on Linux, [online here](http://www.asciitable.com/) otherwise) to convert every 2 hexadecimal digits to the equivalent character.

Comment: Great answer. The file seems to be a tab-separated plain text file, and not an Excel file. It is data pulled from a database table, named `Request`. Thanks for your help.