# SOLR7 error parsing word document

Tags: java, solrcloud, full-text-indexing

I use SOLR7 to full extract windows doc files. i have this error:

o.a.s.h.RequestHandlerBase org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NotOLE2FileException: Invalid header signature; read 0x0A1A0A0D474E5089, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.(HeaderBlock.java:144)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.(HeaderBlock.java:113)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:301)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:124)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.DelegatingParser.parse(DelegatingParser.java:72)
    at org.apache.tika.extractor.ParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor.parseEmbedded(ParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor.java:102)
    at org.apache.tika.extractor.EmbeddedDocumentUtil.parseEmbedded(EmbeddedDocumentUtil.java:220)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.AbstractPOIFSExtractor.handleEmbeddedResource(AbstractPOIFSExtractor.java:124)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.AbstractPOIFSExtractor.handleEmbeddedResource(AbstractPOIFSExtractor.java:100)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.WordExtractor.handlePictureCharacterRun(WordExtractor.java:640)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.WordExtractor.handleParagraph(WordExtractor.java:372)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.WordExtractor.handleHeaderFooter(WordExtractor.java:259)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.WordExtractor.parse(WordExtractor.java:182)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:176)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:132)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingDocumentLoader.load(ExtractingDocumentLoader.java:228)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:68)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2539)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:709)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:515)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:377)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:678)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2018-08-13 13:50:58.445 ERROR (qtp1671846437-23) [c:bdl s:shard1 r:core_node3 x:bdl_shard1_replica_n1] o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall null:org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NotOLE2FileException: Invalid header signature; read 0x0A1A0A0D474E5089, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.(HeaderBlock.java:144)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.(HeaderBlock.java:113)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:301)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:124)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.DelegatingParser.parse(DelegatingParser.java:72)
    at org.apache.tika.extractor.ParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor.parseEmbedded(ParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor.java:102)
    at org.apache.tika.extractor.EmbeddedDocumentUtil.parseEmbedded(EmbeddedDocumentUtil.java:220)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.AbstractPOIFSExtractor.handleEmbeddedResource(AbstractPOIFSExtractor.java:124)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.AbstractPOIFSExtractor.handleEmbeddedResource(AbstractPOIFSExtractor.java:100)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.WordExtractor.handlePictureCharacterRun(WordExtractor.java:640)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.WordExtractor.handleParagraph(WordExtractor.java:372)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.WordExtractor.handleHeaderFooter(WordExtractor.java:259)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.WordExtractor.parse(WordExtractor.java:182)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:176)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser.parse(OfficeParser.java:132)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingDocumentLoader.load(ExtractingDocumentLoader.java:228)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:68)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2539)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:709)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:515)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:377)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:678)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

but with SOLR 5.5 i have no error, any idea ?

Comment: maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33879515/notole2fileexception-invalid-header-signature-read-0x0000000000000000-expecte

Comment: not at all i am using SOLR7 libs are embedded i could not do any things because it is a server. there is no java or other language code....

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes when there is picture in document. the header for the picture is retrieved and POI is expecting something else.... but the header from the document is OK.

```
read 0x0A1A0A0D474E5089, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0
```

the expected is from the document word header, the other is header from picture for example. the parser is waiting always same header even in document if there is other element. change the parser will make the trick.