# How InputStream convert to apache.poi Workbook?

Tags: java, apache-poi, hssfworkbook

I need file excel  to convert in `Workbook` (apache poi).
I get `InputStream`:

```
InputStream in = getInputStream(); // from user file.xls
if(in != null){
    HSSFWorkbook hssfWorkbook = new  HSSFWorkbook(in); //exception
}
```

but next I get exception:

> org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NotOLE2FileException: Invalid header
>   signature; read 0x0005060000100809, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your
>   file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document

InputStream I geting from file was built Apachi Poi

And question [NotOLE2FileException: Invalid header signature; read 0x0000000000000000, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33879515/notole2fileexception-invalid-header-signature-read-0x0000000000000000-expecte)   not work for me

I use Vaadin  framework.

```
MultiFileMemoryBuffer buffer = new MultiFileMemoryBuffer();

Upload upload = new Upload(buffer);
upload.setAcceptedFileTypes("application/vnd.ms-excel");
upload.setMaxFiles(1);
upload.setSizeFull();
upload.addSucceededListener((event) -> {

        name = event.getFileName();

        try (InputStream inputStream = buffer.getInputStream(name) // getInputStream
             ) {
                Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputStream);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Is the file broken? Are you sure that you have the right file in the right format?

Comment: I can open file in LibreOffice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NotOLE2FileException: Invalid header signature; read 0x0000000000000000, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33879515/notole2fileexception-invalid-header-signature-read-0x0000000000000000-expecte)

Comment: Is it still an `.xls` file?

Comment: According to the first bytes `0908100000060500` this appears to be a `*.xls` file in a very old binary `BIFF` format which `apache poi`does not support. Try opening in Excel, resaving as `Excel 97-2003 ... (*.xls)`. Then `apache poi` will be able creating a workbook from it.

Comment: InputStream I geting from file was built Apachi Poi

Comment: Then please show your `getInputStream` code.

Comment: added. After resaving as Excel 97-2003  I can read file in stream. Can I create file  as Excell 97-2003  Apach Poi?

Comment: Where is `event.getFileName()` coming from? As it looks now, that file is a `*.xls` file in a very old binary `BIFF` format which `apache poi` does not supports. Is this an uploaded file? If so, who does it uploading and why does this one uploading files in such an old format? Where is that file comig from? What software has it created?

Comment: I create this file with apach poi: 
 byte[] source =  ((HSSFWorkbook) workbook).getBytes();
 and next save: outputStrem.write(source);

Comment: This way we will not get to an answer. In `byte[] source = ((HSSFWorkbook) workbook).getBytes();` where is the `workbook` coming from? But if you need a byte array containing the bytes of an `*.xls`, why not writing the `HSSFWorkbook` to an `ByteArrayOutputStream` using [HSSFWorkbook.write](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#write-java.io.OutputStream-)? This will be the better solution than [HSSFWorkbook.getBytes](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#getBytes--).

Comment: And btw.: If you finally needs a file, why not simple writing the `HSSFWorkbook` to a file directly?

Comment: You are right.I  rewrote  workbook.write(outputStream) instead  outputStream(workbook.getBytes())   and get  right excell file :) Thank you.

Comment: Then the "bytes of just the HSSF portions" of an `HSSFWorkbook` start `0908100000060500` which definitelly is not any current BIFF header. It then should be mentioned more clearly in [HSSFWorkbook.getBytes](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#getBytes--), that this bytes are **not** "the binary representation of this workbook and all contained sheets, rows, cells, etc.".